# Is there a PPA or Repository for Ethereum?

Tags: linux, ppa, repositories

Is there a PPA or Repository we can add to our system so that we receive automatic updates to our Ethereum software in GNU + Linux?

Comment: see https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/92185/problem-installing-ethereum-via-apt-get-on-debian-buster for debian

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the Ethereum Foundation:
https://launchpad.net/~ethereum/+archive/ubuntu/ethereum

There are 2 primary PPAs, `ethereum` for stable releases and `ethereum-unstable` for develop builds of Geth.  From [Go Ethereum Downloads](https://ethereum.github.io/go-ethereum/downloads)
they are updated automatically.

- Stable releases

  - `ethereum` PPA is updated when a new version of the latest release (currently 1.5) branch is tagged.
- Develop builds

  - `ethereum-unstable` PPA contains "the develop snapshots of go-ethereum, updated automatically when a new commit is pushed" on the `master` branch.

Additional information from the [Ethereum blog](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/11/17/whoa-geth-1-5):

> Beginning with Geth 1.5, we will no longer maintain a separate master
>   branch for latest-stable and develop branch for latest-edge, rather we
>   will switch to **master as the default and development branch of the
>   project**, and each stable release generation will have its own
>   indefinitely living branch (e.g. release/1.4, release/1.5). The
>   release branches will allow people to depend on older generations
>   (e.g. 1.4.x) without finding surprising git issues with history
>   rewrites. And having master as the default development branch would
>   allow developers to use the latest code.

Answer (score 3):

For ArchLinux, you can get geth, mist and the webthree packages from the [user repositories](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/?O=0&K=ethereum), e.g.:

```
yaourt -S ethereum geth mist
```