# Problem installing Ethereum via apt-get on Debian Buster

Tags: debian, ppa

I want to run a geth fullnode (with fast syncmode) to be able to use the JSON RPC. I have a VMWare-based vm set up which fits all the requirements as far as I can see. Domain. Fixed IP address. Disk space. RAM. The works.

Now this is a Debian system on Buster (10) on kernel 4.19 on an emulated x86_64. `uname -a` gives you `Linux hostname 4.19.0-13-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.160-2 (2020-11-28) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Now I want to install ethereum via apt-get to be able to have it automatically updated instead of having to do this always manually. I encountered some problems installing the sources, as the ppa-keys for whatever reason weren't imported. Anyhow, everything is set now:

```
$ ls -l /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ | grep eth
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 144 Jan 11 17:19 ethereum-ubuntu-ethereum-hirsute.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 140 Jan 11 17:04 ethereum-ubuntu-ethereum-hirsute.list.save
```

and

```
$ apt-key list
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg
## truncated
pub   rsa1024 2014-02-10 [SC]
      2A51 8C81 9BE3 7D2C 2031  944D 1C52 189C 923F 6CA9
uid           [ unknown] Launchpad PPA for Ethereum
## truncated
```

which I achieved via `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 2A518C819BE37D2C2031944D1C52189C923F6CA9` (key ID from the launchpad site) and now my `apt-get update` works without any errors:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
## truncated
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ethereum/ethereum/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
## truncated
Reading package lists... Done
```

Yet, when trying to install `ethereum` (or the packages `geth`, `ethereum-unstable`, or so), I get the message "unable to locate package":

```
$ sudo apt-get install ethereum
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ethereum
```

EDIT: Also followed this here: https://linuxconfig.org/install-packages-from-an-ubuntu-ppa-on-debian-linux, but with the same result: "unable to locate..."

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: You can also get a free Ethereum node access from Cloudflare so there is less need to run your own node if the need is simple JSON RPC access: https://www.cloudflare.com/distributed-web-gateway/#ethereum-gateway

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, but I actually want to run my own node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out this was an incompatibility of Ubuntu and Debian. Hard to say what exactly made it work, but here's what I did:

1. Reset the ppa sources for Ethereum for an older Ubuntu-version: `focal` instead of `hirsute`:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ethereum/ethereum/ubuntu focal main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ethereum/ethereum/ubuntu focal main
```

2. The problem following was, that buster provided glibc6 in version 2.19, while 2.32 required. I fixed this by including the `testing` repository in the `sources.list`:

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian testing main contrib non-free
```

and then (re)installing the package `build-essential` along with a general `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`

Downside to this solution: A TON OF dependencies were upgraded to "testing" versions. Anyhow, so far, everything seems to work fine.

So - anyone has a better/"safer" way?

Comment: Compile it or download a bundle: https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/install-and-build/installing-geth#download-standalone-bundle